# LVM Thin Pool on RAID10 + Metadata on RAID1

Tags: lvm, raid, thinpool

Given 2 SSDs and 4 HDDs with their corresponding PVs (`/dev/ssd1`, `/dev/ssd2`, `/dev/hdd1` to `/dev/hdd4`).

> I know, identifiers are not correct, they are just for easier keeping track of what device I'm talking about.

#### What I want

- all the HDDs to build up a RAID10 array
- have a LVM thin pool on this RAID10
- all the SSDs to build up a RAID1 array
- have the metadata for then thin pool being located on this RAID1

#### What I did

1. Create a VG with all physical PVs included

   ```
   vgcreate appdata /dev/sdd1 /dev/sdd2 /dev/hdd1 /dev/hdd2 /dev/hdd3 /dev/hdd4
   ```
2. Create 2 LVs - one for metadata, one for data

   ```
   lvcreate --type raid1 -m 1 -n ThinMetaAD -L 15G appdata /dev/ssd1 /dev/ssd2
   lvcreate --type raid10 -n ThinAD -L 465G appdata /dev/hdd1 /dev/hdd2 /dev/hdd3 /dev/hdd4
   ```
3. Convert according to [lvmthin manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/lvmthin.7.html#:%7E:text=thin%20pool%20creation.-,Tolerate%20device%20failures%20using%20raid,-To%20tolerate%20device)

   ```
   lvconvert --type thin-pool --poolmetadata appdata/ThinMetaAD appdata/ThinAD
   ```

#### What I got

```
$ lsblk

NAME                              MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
ssd                                 8:0    0 223.6G  0 disk
└─ssd1                              8:1    0    16G  0 part
  ├─appdata-ThinAD_tmeta_rmeta_0  252:2    0     4M  0 lvm
  │ └─appdata-ThinAD_tmeta        252:6    0    15G  0 lvm
  │   └─appdata-ThinAD            252:16   0   464G  0 lvm
  └─appdata-ThinAD_tmeta_rimage_0 252:3    0    15G  0 lvm
    └─appdata-ThinAD_tmeta        252:6    0    15G  0 lvm
      └─appdata-ThinAD            252:16   0   464G  0 lvm
hdd                                 8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk
└─hdd1                              8:17   0 465.8G  0 part
  ├─appdata-ThinAD_tdata_rmeta_0  252:7    0     4M  0 lvm
  │ └─appdata-ThinAD_tdata        252:15   0   464G  0 lvm
  │   └─appdata-ThinAD            252:16   0   464G  0 lvm
  └─appdata-ThinAD_tdata_rimage_0 252:8    0   232G  0 lvm
    └─appdata-ThinAD_tdata        252:15   0   464G  0 lvm
      └─appdata-ThinAD            252:16   0   464G  0 lvm
hdd                                 8:32   0 465.8G  0 disk
└─hdd2                              8:33   0 465.8G  0 part
  ├─appdata-ThinAD_tdata_rmeta_1  252:9    0     4M  0 lvm
  │ └─appdata-ThinAD_tdata        252:15   0   464G  0 lvm
  │   └─appdata-ThinAD            252:16   0   464G  0 lvm
  └─appdata-ThinAD_tdata_rimage_1 252:10   0   232G  0 lvm
    └─appdata-ThinAD_tdata        252:15   0   464G  0 lvm
      └─appdata-ThinAD            252:16   0   464G  0 lvm
hdd                                 8:48   0 465.8G  0 disk
└─hdd3                              8:49   0 465.8G  0 part
  ├─appdata-ThinAD_tdata_rmeta_2  252:11   0     4M  0 lvm
  │ └─appdata-ThinAD_tdata        252:15   0   464G  0 lvm
  │   └─appdata-ThinAD            252:16   0   464G  0 lvm
  └─appdata-ThinAD_tdata_rimage_2 252:12   0   232G  0 lvm
    └─appdata-ThinAD_tdata        252:15   0   464G  0 lvm
      └─appdata-ThinAD            252:16   0   464G  0 lvm
hdd                                 8:64   0 931.5G  0 disk
└─hdd4                              8:65   0   466G  0 part
  ├─appdata-ThinAD_tdata_rmeta_3  252:13   0     4M  0 lvm
  │ └─appdata-ThinAD_tdata        252:15   0   464G  0 lvm
  │   └─appdata-ThinAD            252:16   0   464G  0 lvm
  └─appdata-ThinAD_tdata_rimage_3 252:14   0   232G  0 lvm
    └─appdata-ThinAD_tdata        252:15   0   464G  0 lvm
      └─appdata-ThinAD            252:16   0   464G  0 lvm
ssd                           
└─ssd2                       259:5    0    16G  0 part
  ├─appdata-ThinAD_tmeta_rmeta_1  252:4    0     4M  0 lvm
  │ └─appdata-ThinAD_tmeta        252:6    0    15G  0 lvm
  │   └─appdata-ThinAD            252:16   0   464G  0 lvm
  └─appdata-ThinAD_tmeta_rimage_1 252:5    0    15G  0 lvm
    └─appdata-ThinAD_tmeta        252:6    0    15G  0 lvm
      └─appdata-ThinAD            252:16   0   464G  0 lvm
```

#### Question

I'm wondering if the above setup is correct in the sense of what I initially wanted, in particular I'm worried about the 3 levels below `partition` level, like here:

```
hdd                                 8:32   0 465.8G  0 disk
└─hdd2                              8:33   0 465.8G  0 part
>>├─appdata-ThinAD_tdata_rmeta_1  252:9    0     4M  0 lvm
>>│ └─appdata-ThinAD_tdata        252:15   0   464G  0 lvm
>>│   └─appdata-ThinAD            252:16   0   464G  0 lvm
  └─appdata-ThinAD_tdata_rimage_1 252:10   0   232G  0 lvm
    └─appdata-ThinAD_tdata        252:15   0   464G  0 lvm
      └─appdata-ThinAD            252:16   0   464G  0 lvm
```

1. Is my setup correct?
2. If not, what steps are needed to get the desired output in **What I want**?

Answer (score 0):

`lsblk` shows it this way due to general device dependencies. For complex setups, this may not be directly related to physical storage, thus it looks "wrong".

Maybe LVM tools give a clearer picture:

```
# lvs --all --segments --options +seg_le_ranges appdata
  LV                      VG      Attr       #Str Type      SSize  LE Ranges                       
  ThinAD                  appdata twi-a-tz--    1 thin-pool  9.00g [ThinAD_tdata]:0-2303           
  [ThinAD_tdata]          appdata rwi-aor---    2 raid1      9.00g [ThinAD_tdata_rimage_0]:0-2303,[ThinAD_tdata_rimage_1]:0-2303
  [ThinAD_tdata_rimage_0] appdata iwi-aor---    1 linear     9.00g /dev/loop2001:1-2304            
  [ThinAD_tdata_rimage_1] appdata iwi-aor---    1 linear     9.00g /dev/loop2002:1-2304            
  [ThinAD_tdata_rmeta_0]  appdata ewi-aor---    1 linear     4.00m /dev/loop2001:0-0               
  [ThinAD_tdata_rmeta_1]  appdata ewi-aor---    1 linear     4.00m /dev/loop2002:0-0               
  [ThinAD_tmeta]          appdata ewi-aor---    2 raid1     92.00m [ThinAD_tmeta_rimage_0]:0-22,[ThinAD_tmeta_rimage_1]:0-22
  [ThinAD_tmeta_rimage_0] appdata iwi-aor---    1 linear    92.00m /dev/loop1001:1-23              
  [ThinAD_tmeta_rimage_1] appdata iwi-aor---    1 linear    92.00m /dev/loop1002:1-23              
  [ThinAD_tmeta_rmeta_0]  appdata ewi-aor---    1 linear     4.00m /dev/loop1001:0-0               
  [ThinAD_tmeta_rmeta_1]  appdata ewi-aor---    1 linear     4.00m /dev/loop1002:0-0               
  [lvol0_pmspare]         appdata ewi-------    1 linear    92.00m /dev/loop2001:2305-2327
```

I tried to approximate your setup with loop devices, `/dev/loop100x` for meta, `/dev/loop200x` for data. Your output should list other devices and sizes.

You can see all tmeta stuff is on /dev/loop1xxx and all tdata stuff is on /dev/loop2xxx so it should be as you intended.

The exception is the pmspare (pool metadata spare) volume. This is described in the lvmthin manpage.